# how to download patch for pull request in github using github-api

Tags: python, github-api

I am trying to write a script that would download all the open "pull-requests" for a given repo into a folder with the file names as ".patch".

I am using https://pypi.org/project/ghapi/.

I have been able to login and get the list of open pull-requests and also the url that should be used for getting the patch.

However I did not find any API that could be used to directly download the patch.

If the repo is a public repository, I can use the "requests" package directly download it.  However my repo is private, and hence will need authentication.

Here is my sample code

```
from ghapi.core import GhApi
import requests

github_token=<my token>
api=GhApi(owner=<my-org>, repo=<my-repo>,token=github_token )

for (pr_number,patch_url) in map(lambda pr: (pr['number'], pr['patch_url']), api.pulls.list(state="open", per_page=100, page=1 )):
    print(pr_number, patch_url)
    r=requests.get(patch_url, headers={'Authorization':'token '+github_token})
    open("%d.patch"%(pr_number),'wb').write(r.content)
```

Can someone let me know if I am missing something.
I keep getting "Not Found" with the above.
However, if I open the URL directly from my browser, I can see the patch.

Thanks

Comment: It looks like you've mis-spelled "Authorization".

Comment: thanks @larsks I have fixed the typo error and also updated the question.
However, it still has not led to any change in behavior.

Also, if possible I would prefer to use the GhApi to directly from the PR instead of having to use the URL and fetch it directly.

Comment: I managed to get this working with below change.
replace the line 
```r=requests.get(patch_url, headers={'Authorization':'token '+github_token})```
with 
```
owner=<add the name of repo owner>
repo=<name of your repo>
patch_url=f'https://api.github.com/repos/{owner}/{repo}/pulls/{pr_number}
r=requests.get(patch_url, headers={'Authorization':'token '+github_token})```

Ref: https://docs.github.com/en/rest/pulls/pulls?apiVersion=2022-11-28

But I would still like to know if there is a simpler way to get this directly via GhApi instead of having to use raw http request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `patch_url` attribute returned by `api.pulls.list(...)` isn't an API url; you can tell because it doesn't contain the API endpoint (`api.github.com`). That means it doesn't support authentication using an API token. It's meant to be presented to the user and fetched in a browser.

If you want to get a pull request in patch format via the API, you need to fetch the pull request using a specific content-type:

```
for pull in api.pulls.list(state="open", per_page=100, page=1):
    patch = api(pull.url, headers={"Accept": "application/vnd.github.patch"})
    print(patch)
```

The [api documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/pulls/pulls?apiVersion=2022-11-28#custom-media-types-for-pull-requests) shows what content types you can use when fetching pull requests.

---

A warning, because I found out the hard way: while the `requests` module correctly treats headers as case-insensitive (so `accept` is the same as `Accept`), the `ghapi` module does not. When overriding the `Accept` header you must use the same capitalization as the module uses.